# Is there any website for programmer to review other code?

Tags: review

The title is what I want, I'm in school and doing my own project myself, so I really want to have a website that I can post my code there for anyone review it, can I? Thanks.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question should not get downvotes in my opinion, the guy probably had less votes, that made him ask question. The people new to SO, do ask these questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the code works, [Code Review @ Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is an option. Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915) and their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting though.

> If you have a **working piece of code** from your project and are looking for **open-ended feedback** in the following areas:
>
> Best practices and design pattern usage
>       Security issues
>       Performance
>       Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> … then you are in the right place!